# Numbers generator for matrix in specific range

Tags: c++, matrix, numbers, generator

I need some number generator for matrix in c++, but with specific range.
For example, I need random matrix in range <-1,1> or <0,1>.
So I need some function, which parameters are specific intervals.

Thanks

Comment: Define matrix please.

Comment: I have matrix 7x7. And every element is random number from <-1,1>

Comment: Bad definition, zero effort question. Bad combination, this looks doomed to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your compiler supports C++11, you could iterate over the elements of your matrix and randomly initialize them with numbers in the range `[a,b]` like below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>

void fillMatrixRnd(YourMatrix &M, double const a, double const b)
{
  // construct a trivial random generator engine from a time-based seed:
  unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
  std::default_random_engine generator (seed);
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution (a, b);
  for(auto e : M) e = distribution(generator); // Change here according to your needs
}
```